# Mongodb over Lustre?

Tags: mongodb, lustre

I need to install a mongodb instance with a lot of data storage.
We have a Lustre FS with hundreds of terabytes, but when monogdb start show me this error:

```
Mon Jul 15 12:06:50.898 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Mon Jul 15 12:06:50.898 dbexit:
```

But the permissions should be fine:

```
# ls -lart /project/mongodb/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 19 root   root   4096 Jul 15 11:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mongod mongod    0 Jul 15 11:54 mongod.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongod mongod 4096 Jul 15 12:10 .
```

And no other running process:

```
# ps -fu mongod
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
#
```

**Has anyone done this (Lustre+mongodb)?**

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the existing mongod.lock file and it should take care of everything.
If mongodb doesnt exit gracefully it wont clean this file up when it exits so it thinks something may still be running.

Comment: I have already tried that :(